# Set tab text with specific font-family

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

In my application I need to set a custom font-family ("sans-serif-condensed-light") on the Tab Title.

To achieve my intent I used a custom TabLayout found here on StackOverflow.
This is the code

```
public sealed class TabLayout : Android.Support.Design.Widget.TabLayout
{   
    public TabLayout (Context context) : base (context)
    {
        Initialize (null);
    }

    public TabLayout (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base (context, attrs)
    {
        Initialize (attrs);
    }

    public TabLayout (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base (context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
        Initialize (attrs);
    }

    Typeface _typeface;
    void Initialize (IAttributeSet attrs)
    {
        _typeface = UiUtils.GetDefaultTypeface (Context);
    }

    public override void AddTab (Tab tab)
    {
        base.AddTab (tab);

        var mainView = (ViewGroup) GetChildAt (0);
        var tabView = (ViewGroup) mainView.GetChildAt (tab.Position);
        var tabViewChild = tabView.GetChildAt (1);
        ((TextView) tabViewChild).SetTypeface(_typeface, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
    }
}
```

Using this code everything goes well but, if I set the title in a later time using:

```
_tabLayout.GetTabAt (1).SetText ("hi");
```

the new font-family is lost.

I tried using a SpannableString in this way:

```
var _typeface = UiUtils.GetDefaultTypeface (Activity);
            var word2 = new SpannableString (_tabLayout.GetTabAt (1).Text + "a");
            word2.SetSpan (new CustomTypefaceSpan (GetString(Resource.String.default_font_family), _typeface), 0, word2.Length (), SpanTypes.ExclusiveInclusive);
            word2.SetSpan (new ForegroundColorSpan (Resources.GetColor (Resource.Color.textColorPrimary)), 0, 5, SpanTypes.ExclusiveInclusive);

            _tabLayout.GetTabAt (1).SetText (word2);
```

But does not work.

What I0m doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just an idea: what if you create a TextView, set it up with the desired typeface and set it as a custom view to a particular tab? I mean something like `tab.setCustomView(textView)` , then later you could do `((TextView)tab.getCustomView()).setText("hi")` . And if that actually works you wouldn't even have to inherit the TabLayout at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using this approach:

```
    public sealed class TabLayout : Android.Support.Design.Widget.TabLayout
{   
    public TabLayout (Context context) : base (context)
    {
    }

    public TabLayout (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base (context, attrs)
    {
    }

    public TabLayout (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base (context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        base.OnMeasure (widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        SetTextViewStyle (this);
    }

    static void SetTextViewStyle (ViewGroup parent)
    {
        for (int i = parent.ChildCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var child = parent.GetChildAt (i);
            if (child is ViewGroup) {
                SetTextViewStyle((ViewGroup) child);
            } else {
                var c = child as TextView;
                if (c != null) 
                {
                    UiUtils.ApplyFont (c);
                    c.SetAllCaps (false);
                    c.Text = c.Text.ToLower ();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Probably this is not the best way, but it works and by now I didn't see performance issues.